# Magento2 : Any up-to-date Multi-Vendor Marketplaces?

Tags: magento2, marketplace, multi-vendor

I'm trying to use Apptha Marketplace for Magento 2 but it doesn't seem to be compatible with PHP 7.2 because of the use of 'Object' in many of the php files.

> Example:  Fatal error: Cannot use Zend\Form\Annotation\Object as
>   Object because 'Object' is a special class name in
>   public_html/app/code/Apptha/Marketplace/Block/Product/Manage.php on
>   line 35

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source file you can see they have added a note

> Since PHP 7 adds "object" as a reserved keyword, we can no longer have
>   a class * named that and retain PHP 7 compatibility. The original
>   class has been * renamed to "Instance", and this class is now an
>   extension of it. It raises an * E_USER_DEPRECATED to warn users to
>   migrate.

So as advised, use **Zend\Form\Annotation\Instance** instead of **Zend\Form\Annotation\Object**

and this fix might work not tested by myself

https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchBundle/issues/828#issuecomment-443437917